# JSON Json.Net parsing

Tags: json.net

Hi I need to parse the following:

```
{
    "details": {
        "userId": {
            "$": "MyId" 
        },
        "firstName": {
            "$": "MyName" 
        } 
    }
}
```

my problem is the `"$"` ,this is a valid JSON  I tried to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` however the expression with "$" making my object to NULL and this is impossible to make an object with "$" property

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution is to convert "$": to "s":

```
string validJson = jsonData.Replace("\"$\":", "\"s\":");
```